# Dart return multiple coordinates

Tags: class, flutter, dart, coordinates

I'm a bit stuck, i've created a class"CoordXYcenter" who receive a String value (island name) and my method test the name to define  my latitude and longitude.

```
class Maposm extends StatefulWidget {

  final island;
  Maposm(this.island);
  @override
  _MaposmState createState() => _MaposmStat(island);
}

class _MaposmState extends State<Maposm> {

  final island;
  _MaposmState(this.island);
  double _lat= CoordXYcenterisland(island:island).centerlat; // Pb here
  double _long= CoordXYcenterisland(island:island).centerlong;//same

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return new FlutterMap(
    options: new MapOptions(
      center: new LatLng(_lat ,_long),
```

i have an error message :The named parameter 'island' isn't defined. But island is defined in an another classe where the user press a button witch define the value

Comment: The error is telling you that the function `CoordXYcenterisland` does not have a [*named parameter*](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#named-parameters) named `island`.  You haven't shown us the code to `CoordXYcenterisland`, but likely the parameter is named something else or the parameter is a unnamed, positional parameter (in which case you'd need to call it as `CoordXYcenterisland(island)`).

Answer (score 0):

oops my faults old code, i've modfied : CoordXYcenterisland(island),

```
class CoordXYcenterisland {
  final String island;    
  double centerlat,centerlong;

  CoordXYcenterisland(this.island);

    getcenterxy(){  
        if(island.toLowerCase()=='guadeloupe'){
          centerlat=16.120719;
          centerlong=-61.505664;
        }
        else if (island.toLowerCase()=='martinique'){
          centerlat=14.647310;
          centerlong= -60.998896;
        }
        else {      
          centerlat=15.120719;
          centerlong=-61.25;
          }
          return;
    }
}
```

But i still got "can't be accessed in an initializer", is it because i do not return the two coordinates from my method ?

Comment: 1. This isn't an answer and is a separate question. 2. Post the full error message (don't paraphrase it) and indicate which line it's referring to.

Answer (score 0):

yup here is the whole error message i got for the line 20 and 21:The instance member 'island' can't be accessed in an initializer.
Try replacing the reference to the instance member with a different expression [20,36]

```
import 'dart:core';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_map/flutter_map.dart';
import 'package:latlong/latlong.dart';
import 'package:algua_alpha/choose_island.dart';

class Maposm extends StatefulWidget {

  final island;
  Maposm(this.island);
  @override
  _MaposmState createState() => _MaposmState(island);
}

class _MaposmState extends State<Maposm> {

  final island;
  _MaposmState(this.island);
  double _lat= CoordXYcenterisland(island).centerlat;//line 20 error
  double _long= CoordXYcenterisland(island).centerlong;//line 21 error

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return new FlutterMap(
    options: new MapOptions(
      center: new LatLng(_lat ,_long),
      zoom: 10.4,
    ),
    layers: [
      new TileLayerOptions(
       urlTemplate: "https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png",
        subdomains: ['a', 'b', 'c']
      ),
      // new MarkerLayerOptions(
      //   markers: [
      //     new Marker(
      //       width: 80.0,
      //       height: 80.0,
      //       point: new LatLng(51.5, -0.09),
      //       builder: (ctx) =>
      //       new Container(
      //         child: new FlutterLogo(),
      //       ),
      //     ),
      //   ],
      // ),
    ],
  );
}
}
```

Comment: There are restrictions on what you can use to initialize members directly.  In this case, you should initialize them in the constructor's initialization list or in the constructor's body.

Comment: And again, this isn't an answer.  If you have other questions, yous should post new questions instead.